# VS17 not initializing pointer

Tags: c, struct, visual-studio-2017

My problem is that this code is not working in VS 2017 while in CLion it works.
VS says:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error (active)  E0144
>   a value of type `void *` cannot be used to initialize an entity of type `queue_t*`

therefor the program is not allocating the memory.

Further every pointer like the example above is not working.

Does somebody here know why that is the case, why VS thinks that this would be a `void`?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

struct packet_t {
    double d;
    int i;
    long l;
    char *p;
    struct queue_t *queue;
};

struct queue_t {
    char *name;
    int size;
    int entries;
    double time;
    struct packet_t **packets;
    int read;
    int write;
    long lost;
    long total;
};


int decision = -1;
int isRunning = 1;

void logError(char message[]) {
    printf("ERROR: %s", message);
}

struct queue_t *queue_create(char *name, int size) {
    struct queue_t *q = malloc(sizeof(struct queue_t));

    if (!q) {
        logError("could not allocate memory!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        q->name = name;
        q->size = size;
        q->entries = 0;
        q->read = 0;
        q->write = 0;
        q->total = 0;
        q->lost = 0;

        q->packets = malloc(size * sizeof(struct packet_t *));

        if (!q->packets) {
            logError("could not allocate memory!\n");
            free(q);
            return 0;
        }

        struct packet_t **current;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            current = q->packets + i;
            *current = NULL;
        }
    }
    return q;
}

int packet_destroy(struct packet_t *packet) {
    //TODO test if deleted ?
    if (packet) {
        free(packet);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

long queue_store(struct queue_t *queue, struct packet_t *packet) {
    if (queue->entries < queue->size) {
        packet->queue = queue;
        *(queue->packets + queue->write) = packet;

        queue->write++;

        if (queue->write == queue->size) {
            queue->write = 0;
        }

        queue->total++;
        queue->entries++;

        return queue->total;
    }
    //cant save packet ->destroy
    packet_destroy(packet);
    queue->lost++;
    return 0;
}

struct packet_t *queue_retrieve(struct queue_t *queue) {
    if (queue->entries == 0) return NULL;

    struct packet_t **current = queue->packets + queue->read;
    struct packet_t *packet = *current;

    *current = NULL;
    if (packet->queue) {
        packet->queue = NULL;
    }
    queue->entries--;

    queue->read++;
    if (queue->read == queue->size) {
        queue->read = 0;
    }

    return packet;
}

struct packet_t *packet_create(int i, double d, long l, char *p) {
    struct packet_t *new = malloc(sizeof(struct packet_t));
    if (new) {
        new->i = i;
        new->d = d;
        new->l = l;
        new->p = p;
    }
    else {
        logError("failed to allocate memory");
    }

    return new;
}

int queue_destroy(struct queue_t *queue) {
    if (!queue) {
        logError("could not find queue!");
        return 0;
    }
    struct packet_t *p;

    for (int i = 0; i < queue->size; i++) {
        p = *(queue->packets + i);
        packet_destroy(p);
    }

    //TODO test if not needed as it's already free'd in packet_destroy
    free(queue->packets);
    free(queue);
    return 0;
}

long test_queue(int val) {
    int sum = 0, finalTime = 0;
    clock_t startTime, finalTicks;
    startTime = clock();

    while (finalTime < val) {
        struct queue_t *q = queue_create("test", 10);
        queue_destroy(
            sum++;
        finalTicks = (clock() - startTime);
        //        printf("ticks: %d\n", finalTicks);
        finalTime = (int)floor((finalTicks / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC));
        //        printf("time: %d\n", finalTime);
    }

    printf("Runtime: %d\n seconds", finalTime);
    printf("Added and removed %d queues\n", sum);
}

long test_packets(int val) {
    int finalTime = 0;
    struct queue_t *q = queue_create("test", 10);
    clock_t startTime, finalTicks;
    startTime = clock();

    while (finalTime < val) {
        struct packet_t *t = packet_create(finalTime, finalTime + 1, finalTime + 2, NULL);
        queue_store(q, t);
        packet_destroy(queue_retrieve(q));
        finalTicks = (clock() - startTime);
        //        printf("ticks: %d\n", finalTicks);
        finalTime = (int)floor((finalTicks / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC));
        //        printf("time: %d\n", finalTime);
    }

    printf("Runtime: %d\n", finalTime);
    printf("Successfully added %li entries\n", q->total);
    printf("Failed to add %li entries\n", q->lost);

    queue_destroy(q);
}

void resetDecision() {
    decision = -1;
    isRunning = 1;
}

void checkDecision() {
    while (decision != 0 && decision != 1 && decision != 2) {
        printf("Select option:\n (1) Run queue test \n (2) Run packet test \n(0) to cancel \n");
        scanf("%d", &decision);
    }
    if (decision == 0) {
        isRunning = 0;
    }
    else if (decision == 1) {
        int val = 0;
        while (val <= 0) {
            printf("Enter the time to test");
            scanf("%d", &val);
        }
        printf("Running test for %d seconds....\n", val);
        test_queue(val);
    }
    else if (decision == 2) {
        int val = 0;
        while (val <= 0) {
            printf("Enter the time to test");
            scanf("%d", &val);
        }
        printf("Running test for %d seconds....\n", val);
        test_packets(val);
    }

    if (decision != 0)
        resetDecision();
}

int main() {
    while (isRunning) {
        checkDecision();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is because you are compiling it in C++ mode. Switch to C mode to fix the problem.

Comment: Your code does not compile, there is a problem in `test_queue` right after the line `struct queue_t *q = queue_create("test", 10);`, something is missing there.

Comment: While this is definitely a C program, you are still making something up. Lines like `queue_destroy(` (and the rest is missing) in `test_queue` will not compile in any compiler. Yet you are claiming that it compiles in CLion... How is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are compiling your program as a C++ program. In C++ there is no implicit conversion from the type `void *` to pointer of other object type.

So you need to write using explicit casting like

```
struct queue_t *q = ( struct queue_t * )malloc(sizeof(struct queue_t));
```

Or you should consider your program as indeed a C++ program and use the operator new instead of the C function malloc.